# PROPOSAL - The Great 5 Year Anniversary Bounty Bonanza

Tags: discussion, status-completed, fun, competitions, bounties

### The Proposals

Our 5 year anniversary falls on the 28th of June this year, if we consider our birth date to be [the date our public beta went live](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel). Time to celebrate this Travel.SE style - with a competition!

Below are two possible proposals:

1. For the whole month of June we could run a bounty giveaway. Users sign up and agree to place and keep three bounties live during the entire month. In other words, each participant starts with three bounties on the 1st of June, and must end with three bounties on the 30th of June. Whenever a bounty is awarded or expire, it must be replaced by another bounty.  This option costs the participants about 600 rep (3 bounties * 4 weeks * 50)
2. The other way to do this would be to define a rota, so that each participant posts a bounty on their assigned days. The result here would be to have the community create a total of 30 bounties posted throughout the month. This could be our plan B in case we don't get enough participants for proposal 1. This option costs the participants about 150 rep (3 bounties * 50).

Then we go and advertise this in other SE websites, asking people to come and answer questions here, luring them in with prizes and rep. The objective being to reduce our unanswered rate whilst gathering new potential contributors.

Ideally we'd need a minimum of 10 participants to make this interesting. That would amount to a minimum of 30 bounties per week, if all remain in the competition.

The objective of this post is to discuss the idea with the community, to see if we like it and improve the concept.

I have posted the two proposals as answers. Please upvote the one you like best. If you have a third (or fourth or twentieth) proposal, by all means post it as an answer.

### Finding a bounty-worthy question...

Not to worry. The final two weeks of May 2016 is for the "Great Flood of Bounty Worthy Questions", where we flood the site with incredibly wonderful questions that can be bountied. The winner of that mini-competition gets street-cred for creativity.

### Still can't find any?

Not to worry.  Any question will do. Answered, unanswered, old, new, whatever... As long as it's a real question that is half-way decent, you can put a bounty on it to bring it more attention. Remember, the big objective here is to have a bounty bonanza that attracts lots of new people from other SO sites who see what's on and think, "...hey! I can pick up some rep over on Travel by collecting a few bounties...". Maybe they will, maybe they won't, but perhaps a few will go on to become great TSE companions.

### Don't have rep to spare for bounties?

Not to worry. If you want to participate but are struggling with reputation, see "**finding a bounty worthy question**" above.  You can jump in and help by  saving up some incredibly fascinating questions. Do you like to prospect for investment properties while travelling for leisure?  Do you like to go ice-fishing in the Hudson Bay? Are you looking for a place to go bead-begging when the Mardi Gras is over? Did you ever think about wind-surfing down the Danube? Why is there a golf club next to Nuuk airport? Which parts of the underground city in Verona are open to the public?  Put your thinking caps on!

### Proposed Community Advert

This image is 600 x 500 x 300dpi

[image]

Comment: I love the idea.  I am happy with EITHER option.  If done, it will create a pull factor and we can get lots of new users involved.  Very nice!  I'm in!

Comment: All in! I'll sign up for both proposals

Comment: Guess I've got rep to burn these days, so sure.

Comment: +2 if I could for the edit concerning the "Great Flood of Bounty Worthy Questions" and question selection. At first I had my doubts as the unanswered question ain't that many (and some already had bounties expire on them or are answered in comments).

Comment: I prefer the rota, as it's then easier for people to give away more than the minimum

Comment: Yeah, why not, it's ridiculous for me to have more rep than on SO or Drupal SE anyways.

Comment: I'd prefer to make it that the people offering bounties maintain at least 3 active bounties the entire month! And each bounty should be 100 or more.

Comment: Can have a competition at the same time between the bounty people to see who can give away the most bounties ;)

Comment: Also I totally volunteer to be one of these, although I'll be in India for two of the weeks, so access to update bounties will be intermittent.

Comment: 7 participants so far. The hurdle is 10 so let's hear from more volunteers peeps

Comment: I think the objective of the bounties (Aside from fun, attracting new members, etc etc) should also be to target unanswered questions. If we can use the bounties to drive the unanswered questions towards 0, that's a win for everyone involved.

Comment: While I am happy to give away some points, I am still careful with points as I want to reach the 10k milestone sometime not too far distant. 3 times 100 times 4 weeks, that is a lot of points. If you put the bar high, I may have to chicken out.

Comment: @Willeke 3x50 (you can do bounties of 50).  And remember, if you answer some of the other bountied questions, you'll get that rep back in droves ;)

Comment: @user568458 Would you care to explain that in more detail? You can also suggest a new proposal as an answer.

Comment: @Willeke, you can help think up some wonderful questions that we can put bounties on. I have 9 banked so far to ask in the last week of May so that they qualify for bounties on 1 June

Comment: @GayotFow If I was good in asking questions I would ask more. Most I think up are duplicates or near as no never mind.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Proposal n. 1

**Participants must have three bounties on offer throughout the duration of the bonanza.**

This proposal wins.

Mark created a [chat event for the Bonanza](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule). Let's make sure that the interested users register there.

Answer (score 12):

### Proposal n. 3

Let's not make this only for the super-high-rep people. You choose your level of participation when you sign up:

- **"Gold" giveaway.** Gold-level participants commit to having **three** open bounties throughout the duration.
- **"Silver" giveaway.** Silver-level participants commit to having **two** open bounties throughout the duration.
- **"Bronze" giveaway.** Bronze-level participants commit to having **one** open bounty throughout the duration.

Answer (score 11):

### Proposal n. 2

Participants define a rota so that each participant posts a bounty on their assigned days.

Upvote this if you prefer this proposal.