# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election

Travel's [second moderator election](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Mark Mayo]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes! (Not that he needs it. ;-)

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4789024841531392/0).

Comment: Congratulations Mark! Just wondering, Jon, is there a reason why the vote tallies on the summary link are shown to 6 decimal places? e.g. why Mark's reported as having `152.000000` votes not `152`? Or why the vote threshold isn't rounded up?

Comment: @user568458 read up on the Senatorial rules (and Meek variation) for STV - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Gregory - basically after the 1st round, fractional votes are very much a thing.

Comment: @user568458: For a causal explanation: [Fair Elections and STV](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/03/fair-elections-and-stv/). When there is one position and the candidate wins a majority, the counting system is overkill.

Answer (score 24):

Thanks to all who voted, and to the other amazing candidates - it's fantastic to see that when we grow further and need more, or if someone else steps down, there are already other well-supported candidates waiting in the wings.  It was also amazing to see almost no negativity in an election, with people old and new stepping up and sharing their thoughts.

This is nearly a [five-year old community](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3582/101) and I look forward to it growing further still.

Comment: You deserve it, and had my vote. Good luck wielding the mighty diamond.

Comment: Welcome back (to the mod team), @MarkMayo! :)