# Thank you Mark Mayo!

Tags: discussion, moderation

Today, Mark Mayo [resigned as a moderator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58350761#58350761), claiming to be burned out on multiple fronts. I'd like to thank him for his service to the site as a moderator.

Mark was one of the site's [initial beta moderators](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/215/11329), appointed shortly after the site went into public beta, and was [elected](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3609/2016-community-moderator-election-results) back into the moderator position in the 2016 election. He's also been the site's [highest-reputation user](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/273/alltime/travel/2011-06-21/101#101) for many years, contributing nearly 2,000 answers over the course of this site. In addition to that, he's [won many site competitions](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3152/11329): the [April 2015 Answerathon](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/april-answerathon-3-remain) and at least four photo competitions, not to mention others.

My first interaction with him (which I can recall) was when he [put a bounty on one of my questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106542/what-is-the-current-status-of-airside-connections-at-lax) that wasn't receiving good answers. All my later interactions with him have been nothing but positive.

Please join me in thanking Mark Mayo for his service to the site as a moderator.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

@gparyani Thank you so much for your kind words and a wonderful write up.  I'm not going anywhere, just giving someone else a chance to put their stamp on a site and to enjoy the fun/challenges that come with a mod role ;)

I'll be in [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) occasionally as well of course :P

Answer (score 23):

Thank you Mark Mayo for your service!

You are by far, [the most generous user on Travel.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/1134857/users-offering-the-most-reputation-through-bounties) (in terms of number of bounties offered):

[image]

Your generosity is much appreciated and will definitely be remembered along with your hard work as a mod.

Answer (score 8):

Mark, all in all I am happy to read this. Your health is the most important asset you own. Knowing that you recognise that something isn't well with you, and that you are making a conscious choice to take care of it and yourself makes me happy. Get well and keep in touch. You know where to find us! Talk to you soon, old friend.